# Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled: NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have written this function in String Extension and can't figure out the error.

```
func isEmail() -> Bool {
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", options: [.CaseInsensitive])

    return regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count)) != nil
}
```

The error is:

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`NSRegularExpression(pattern:)` throws an error if the pattern is invalid. In your case, the pattern is *fixed*, so an invalid pattern
would be a *programming error*.

This is a use-case for the "forced-try" expression with `try!`:

```
extension String {
    func isEmail() -> Bool {
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$",
            options: [.CaseInsensitive])

        return regex.firstMatchInString(self, options:[],
            range: NSMakeRange(0, utf16.count)) != nil
    }
}
```

`try!` disables the error propagation so that the method does not
throw an error (which the caller has to catch). It will abort with a
runtime exception if the pattern is invalid, which helps to find
programming errors early.

Note also that `NSRange()` counts the length of `NSString`, i.e. the number of  UTF-16 code points, so 
`characters.count` should be `utf16.count`, otherwise it might crash
e.g. with Emoji characters.

Comment: http://emailregex.com/ suggests slightly different pattern - `[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}` specifically for Swift. What do you think?

Comment: @Michal: The above code uses the `. CaseInsensitive` option for case-insensitive matching, and your pattern allows both uppercase and lowercase letters. The result is the same.

Comment: Awesome solution, but I'd use a property instead of a function to maintain coherence with String.isEmpty.

    var isEmail: Bool { ...

Comment: @Michal there is no sensible regex to check for legal email addresses

Comment: Xcode 7.3.1 gives "error: Force Try Violation: Force tries should be avoided. (force_try)"

Comment: @MaxMacLeod: That looks like a SwiftLint rule: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/Source/SwiftLintFramework/Rules/ForceTryRule.swift, not an Xcode error.

Comment: yeah you could well be right. Seems like a valid use case to me. I guess SwiftLint doesn't see that the string is constant

Comment: @MaxMacLeod: SwiftLint just sees the string "try!" and complains. Note that you can disable rules locally.

Answer (score 13):

That's because that initializer can now throw an exception, so you need to `try` to call it and be prepared to `catch` the exception. You can do this by adding `try` before the initializer and annotating your method with `throws`.

```
extension String {
    func isEmail() throws -> Bool {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", options: [.CaseInsensitive])

        return regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count)) != nil
    }
}
```

Then when you want to call the method, do it from within a `do` block and catch the error that comes out.

```
do {
    try "person@email.com".isEmail()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Note: I've also updated your `regex.firstMatchInString` call to reflect the fact that the `options` parameter can no longer take a nil value.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like try catch :

```
extension String {
    func matchPattern(patStr:String)->Bool {
            var isMatch:Bool = false
            do {
                let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: patStr, options: [.CaseInsensitive])
                let result = regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count))

                if (result != nil)
                {
                    isMatch = true
                }
            }
            catch {
                isMatch = false
            }
            return isMatch
    }
}
```

check string is correct email format :

```
let emailInput:String = "checkthis@gmail.com"
if (emailInput.matchPattern("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$"))
{
     print("this is e-mail!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use string.rangeOfString, and specify the option to .RegularExpressionSearch. It's simple.

```
func isEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
    return email.rangeOfString("^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil
}
```

Comment: could you edit your solution with a bit more detail please?

Comment: I get the following error when I try this in swift 3: **bold** `execution failed: error: Patterns.playground:2:12: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'rangeOfString'
    return email.rangeOfString("^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil`. There must be an extension on String that you're using that is not included by default.