# End of NSAttributedString with emojis left unformatted

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

The end of my `NSAttributedString` with emojis in the contents is not being formatted. I'm trying to format the entire string (set the text color to white in this example, for simplification), but some of the text stays unformatted when put in a `UILabel`.

[image]

Currently, I'm using

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: contents)

attributedString.addAttribute(
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
    value: UIColor.white,
    range: NSMakeRange(0, contents.characters.count)
)

label.attributedText = attributedString
```

I've also tried getting the length by using `contents.utf8.count` but get the same result.

I noticed that the number of unformatted characters is the same as the number of emojis in the string. Could that have something to do with what's going on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`String.characters.count` returns the number of *rendered characters* in the string. Some emojis (such as flags and race-specific ones) are a combination of two or more UTF characters that are rendered into one character, in order to allow for more emojis.

`UTF` stands for *Unicode Transformation format*, or [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) for short. It allows for computers, phones, tablets, and everything else electronic to use the same  standardized set of characters.

Those who implement it can chose how to render the text, but it is massively important that devices communicate using a standardized character set. Otherwise, sending the message "Hello, World" to someone may show up as "Ifmmp, Xpsme"

In order to get the actual length of the string for use in `NSMakeRange`, use `NSAttributedString.length` or `Int("\(contents.endIndex)")`.

So, the code should look like this

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: contents)

attributedString.addAttribute(
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
    value: UIColor.white,
    range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
)

label.attributedText = attributedString
```

This will now produce the correctly formatted text

[image]

Comment: Your solution is correct, but the explanation could be improved (what is a UTF character?). – `String.characters.count` counts extended grapheme clusters, whereas NSRange is related to NSString and that counts UTF-16 code points. Therefore an alternative solution would be to use `NSMakeRange(0, contents.utf16.count)` as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30845969/1187415.

Comment: Works great. what a time saver