# Swift Regular Expression error

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I create the swift regular expression to detect font.I got the following error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

What wrong in my code???

```
let regexZG = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s\u{1031}| ေ[က-အ]်|[က-အ]း", options:nil, error:nil)
```

Comment: The `error` management has changed since I don't remember which version of Swift. Should be the case here. Are you up to date?

Comment: I'm using xcode 7.3.1 and swift 2.2

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845495/how-to-use-nsregularexpression-in-swift or other recent questions about NSRegularExpression, there should be plenty examples.

Comment: Try `let regexZG = try  NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s\u{1031}| ေ[က-အ]်|[က-အ]း", options:[])`

Answer (score 3):

By 7.3/2.2 all error parameters taking NSErrorPointer had been transitioned to throwable errors.  In addition, empty option sets now use the set notation, so try:

```
do {
    let regexZG = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s\u{1031}| ေ[က-အ]်|[က-အ]း", options:[])
    // do some stuff with regexZG here
}
catch error {
    print("NSRegularExpression init failed: \(error)")
    // do something imaginative here
}
```